# Array remaining empty in spite of adding objects in it

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have an array in which I'm adding objects, but the array is remaining empty even after adding the objects. Here are the code:

**Event.h**

```
@interface Event : NSObject
@property NSString *name;
@end
```

**Code where objects are added to the array**

```
NSMutableArray *events;
NSArray *event_string = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];

    for (NSString *currentEventString in event_string) {
        Event *currentEvent = [Event new];
        [currentEvent setName:currentEventString];
        [events addObject:currentEvent];

    }
    NSLog(@"Number of events:%d",[events count]);
```

I'm getting this output:

```
Number of events:0
```

Comment: Initialize `events` array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initiate events array as following:

```
NSMutableArray *events = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to init this array first.

```
NSMutableArray *events = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Answer (score 2):

What Tomasz said - you need to allocate and initialize your array. Right now the pointer to the array object is null.

The reason you get the strange results is that Objective C (unlike languages such as Java, C++ and C#) will happily let you invoke methods on a null object without crashing or throwing exceptions. The result is then "0" values such as null for pointers/objects, 0 for calculations etc.

It's a little different, but inpractice it works well, and simplifies many algorithms.